# Duplicating UITextFields in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITable` with cells containing a `UILabel` or `UITextField`.  When I update the text in one cell, its also updates the text in another cell further down in the table.

I have found a number of answers which point to the way dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier reuses the cell.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to resolve the issue.  Whatever I try either makes no difference or causes the cells to be empty.

This is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld", @"DataCell_", (long)indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckListCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
}

id obj = [stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

question = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
question.text = [obj valueForKey:@"Question"];

response = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:102];  //THIS IS GETTING DUPLICATED
response.placeholder = [obj valueForKey:@"Question"];

checklistSwitch = (UISwitch *) [cell viewWithTag:103];
cellCheck = cell;

//ResponseTypes C=Checkbox, R=Radiobox, TF=Textfield, TA=Textarea, N=Number, M=Misc
if ([[obj valueForKey:@"ResponseType"] isEqualToString:@"C"] || [[obj valueForKey:@"ResponseType"] isEqualToString:@"R"]) {

    question.hidden = FALSE;
    response.hidden = TRUE;
    if ([[obj valueForKey:@"Checked"] boolValue])
        cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

} else if ([[obj valueForKey:@"ResponseType"] isEqualToString:@"N"]) {

    checklistSwitch.hidden = TRUE;
    question.hidden = TRUE;
    response.hidden = FALSE;
    cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

} else {

    checklistSwitch.hidden = TRUE;
    question.hidden = TRUE;
    response.hidden = FALSE;
    cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [response setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];

}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: where did you call the reload tableview?

Comment: You should not calculate cellID. The purpose of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier  is to dequeue and then reuse your cell. So, all cells must have the same cell ID which you setup in Interface Builder.

Comment: @Stonz2, note that while you did edit the post, you also [approved the changes as well](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7298281). Personally I think incorrect grammar was added.

Comment: @gunr2171 Apologies. I had meant to remove that when I changed the edit (which properly moved the end of the code block) but must have forgotten.

Comment: @Stonz2 remember this also an "edit and reject". In cases like these where the editor did a small number of changes this would be the best case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, i was going around in circles trying to figure it out.  I used an NSDIctionary to store the question and response as per @Stonz2 then in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` I checked whether there was a value for the question and updated the cell with the response, or nil if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the values that are being entered into the `response` fields and apply them appropriately to cells as they are displayed. For instance, if the user types something into the a cell, you could have an `NSMutableArray` that would house that response in the respective index.

Then, when you display your cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
response = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
response.placeholder = [obj valueForKey:@"Question"];
response.text = responseValues[indexPath.row];
```

Just make sure that your array housing the responses is initially set up with the appropriate number of indices and empty strings.

The reason that your text is being duplicated in later cells when they're reused is because at no point do you reset the contents of the `UITextField`, you're only changing the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to subclass UITableViewCell and refactor your code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [_tableView registerClass:[YourTableViewCellSubClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([YourTableViewCellSubClass class])];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YourTableViewCellSubClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([YourTableViewCellSubClass class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (XYZ){
        [self configureXYZCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    if (ABC){
        [self configureABCCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self configureSomeCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)configureXYZCell:(YourTableViewCellSubClass *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.label.text = self.datasource[indexPath.row];
    cell.textfield.text = ... 
    cell.switch.on = ...    
}

- (void)configureABCCell:(YourTableViewCellSubClass *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.label = 
    cell.textfield = 
    cell.switch =   
}

- (void)configureSomeCell:(YourTableViewCellSubClass *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.label = 
    cell.textfield = 
    cell.switch =   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the cell is being reused due to which the previous value of the `UITextfield` is still retained in the reused cell..Make use of the callback

`tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

This is called just as the cell goes outside the visible area. 
Try setting the text in the text field text to nil or `@""`over here. Should work.